# Network Manager always starts disconnected

Tags: networking, network-manager

For some reason, my new Ubuntu 14.04 Desktop machine always starts disconnected from the network.  I'm quite sure I did something to the Network Manager when putting it on a static IP address.

After a reboot, I go into the Network control panel and turn it on, and everything is okay.  Same situation if I restart the Network-manager service.

Looking for suggestions on where to check for the setting.

- I checked /etc/NetworkManager/NetworkManager.conf and `managed=true`
- I checked /var/lib/NetworkManager/NetworkManager.state and `NetworkingEnabled=true`

I'm running this as a VM so there's no WiFi or anything; networking comes back fine as soon as I connect via the control panel.

Thoughts?

Comment: Try to run a `nm-connection-editor`. Edit the connection you want to have and in General tab switch on "Automatically connect to this network when it is available".

Comment: I think you are on the right track.  The eth0 (ifupdown) connection is grayed out for editing.  Checking via the Network connection manager panel, I see that the check box is unchecked (but grayed out).  I will look for another way to set it.

Answer (score 0):

Note to self: make sure that the router is also set to reserve the static IP address.  Once I updated the router (which I had forgotten to do), everything worked like a charm.